# Create sql view with matching columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
Users

UserId       Name
---------    --------
1            a
2            b
3            c
1            d
7            e

UsersComments
commentId Message UserId
  1         aa      1
  2         bb      3
  3         cc      2
  4         dd      3
```

I want to create a view in which i can refer users to the amount of comments they have done, the idea is to add also some other interactions they have on the website so having a colum on users table its not a solution.

So far i have this query:

```
CREATE VIEW userstats AS ( (SELECT UserId FROM Users) , (SELECT count(commentId) FROM UsersComments GROUP BY UserId))
```

The problem is that there may be users that havent done any comment yet, the other problem is how to join the amount of comments per user to its corresponding id.

```
SELECT UserId, count(commentId) FROM UsersComments GROUP BY UserId
```

isnt a solution cause as i said, there will be other metrics for users such as likes or uploaded contents.

How could this be done?

Comment: Your `userId` field is not unique. I assume that's a typo in your sample data. But if it's not, I suggest you ensure keeping a unique `userId`. It will save you a load of work later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done without creating a view.

The question you seem to asking is "What query can return the specified resultset?"

Based on what information we can glean from the syntax you posted (does that query even run?)

This will return the specified resultset,

```
 SELECT u.userid
      , COUNT(c.userid) AS count_usercomments
   FROM users u
   LEFT
   JOIN usercomments c
     ON c.userid = u.userid
  GROUP BY u.userid
```

If you are going to create a view, you first need a SELECT query that returns the resultset you want to return.

Because of the performance impact introduced by using views in MySQL (the performance impact can be negligible in some cases, but can range from significant to crippling in others), I'm not going to provide syntax for creating a view. (I believe that introducing a view unnecessarily has the potential to create a bigger problem than whatever problem is being solved by creating a view.

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q: Why do you think that views are not a good idea?**

**A:** I didn't say that views were not a good idea. What I said was: introducing an unnecessary view has the *potential* to create problems that are *bigger* than whatever problem the view was implemented as a solution for.

When we don't have an understanding of *how* MySQL processes views (which is much different than how views are processed in other databases), we can unwittingly *create* some significant performance problems.

**Q: I would love to be able to just use a result set but making this queries take too long,**

**A:** I would love a pony. And free pizza.

A **`VIEW`** object is a query. That query produces a resultset whenever a query is executed against the VIEW.

Taking a query that "takes too long" and turning that into a view definition doesn't do *anything* to make that query faster.

**Q: wouldnt it be faster if i already have a view constantly being updated?**

**A:** Well, if we had a properly indexed table we could run queries against, that might make things faster.

But again, in MySQL, a `VIEW` object is just a query. It is *not* a stored result set that is "constantly being updated".

When we run a query that references a view (whether that's a `VIEW` object defined in the databse, or an inline view, defined in the SQL text of a query... the view query is executed and the rows returned are materialized into what MySQL refers to as a **derived table**.

As an example, here's a query that includes an inline view definition. (This is just an example for illustration, this is **not** an example of a query that we would actually want to use.)

```
    SELECT v.col
      FROM ( 
              SELECT t.col
               FROM hugetable t
           ) v
     WHERE v.col = 'foo'
```

When that query is executed, MySQL first executes the query for the inline view `v`. That query runs just the same as it would if we were to issue that query separately; the difference is that the resultset (i.e. the set of rows returned) from that query are temporarily stored as a "**derived table**". (That's the terminology that MySQL uses for it, "derived table".

MySQL will use the MEMORY engine to store that, if the resultset is small enough, and if it doesn't contain any column datatypes not supported by the MEMORY engine. Otherwise, MySQL uses the MyISAM storage engine, and spins that resultset out to disk.

Once the derived table is populated, then the outer query runs, using the "derived table" as the rowsource, just like a regular MyISAM table. There are no indexes defined on the derived table, so a full scan is basically the only access method that MySQL has for it. The outer query will check each row in the derived table to see if it meets the predicates in the outer query. (There are actually some improvements in MySQL 5.6.x, where the optimizer can create an index on the derived table; before 5.6, there are *no* indexes on the derived table.)

Once the query completes, the derived table is deallocated. The resultset is not persisted, it's gone.

A subsequent reference to the same view, even in the same session, will cause that view query to be executed again.

If we create a `VIEW` object, for example:

```
    CREATE VIEW myview
    AS
        SELECT t.col
          FROM hugetable t
```

And we write a query that references the `VIEW`, for example:

```
    SELECT v.col
      FROM myview v
     WHERE v.col = 'foo'
```

The behavior is execution plan is *exactly* the same as with the inline view. (There's an extra step of looking up the view definition, to get the SQL for the query, and maybe some privilege checks, et al.), but aside from that, at execution time, it behaves exactly like the inline view.

Note that predicates in the outer query do *not* get pushed down into the view query. And there is no "stored result set" for the view. It's materialized each time the view is accessed.

Views are not a "bad idea" per se. There are times that a view is the best way to return a resultset. (I make frequent use of inline views my queries.)

The problems come when we don't understand *how* views are processed in MySQL. When we create `VIEW` objects, those tend to get referenced in *other* queries where they aren't the most appropriate solution.

For example, this query returns an equivalent resultset to the query example above. But a difference here is that the predicate on col is now included in the view definition, MySQL can make effective use of an index to eliminate boatloads of rows, and access only the required rows. This produces a much smaller derived table (more likely to use the MEMORY engine), and the outer query will run much more quickly because there are fewer rows to scan.

```
    SELECT v.col
      FROM (
             SELECT h.col
               FROM hugetable h
              WHERE h.col = 'foo'
           ) v
```

One issue with a `VIEW` object is that it "hides" information about the query, and restricts our options in influencing the optimizer to produce a resultset efficiently.

Comment: why you think that views are not a good idea? i would love to be able to just use a result set but making this queries take too long, wouldnt it be faster if i already have a view constantly being updated?

Comment: Q: I would love to be able to just use a result set but making this queries take too long,

You are right, i didnt express myself right, i need to take several records from this view from different subquerys but now i understand it better, insted of using a view i will be using a dinamic generated table! thanks!

Comment: @gabriel: Your question was about creating a view, I believe I answered your question (i.e. "to create view, you need a SELECT statement".)  I find it hard to believe that `CREATE VIEW`  statement provided in the answer you selected has done anything in the way of improving performance. Your question now seems to be "How can I get the specified resultset more efficiently?" The answer to that question doesn't need to be mucked up with all the the nonsense about "creating a view". Adding `CREATE VIEW` in front of SELECT statement that performs poorly doesn't improve performance of the SELECT.

Comment: @gabrielmellace: If you want to **improve the performance** of the query that returns the resultset, you'll need to run EXPLAIN to see what execution plan MySQL is using. (It's entirely possible that suitable indexes are not available.) If the tables are really large, and you are needing to get this "count of comments" frequently, you may want to consider "caching" the count, if you don't need "up to the minute" precision, and you can live with a count that's an hour old. To cache that resultset in MySQL, you'd need a **table** to store it. A **view** won't do it.

Comment: thanks spencer ! i now see the difference! lets see if i get it, then a view its only a way of "storing" a sql statement, not a resultset, like a shortcut

Comment: @gabrielmellace: Yes! This is true in MySQL. (Other relational database systems, like Oracle, have a objects called "materialized views"... they start off the same as view, BUT, the resultset from the view query is "materialized" into a real table. In MySQL, you'd have to emulate that behavior, by creating a **table**, and the storing the resultset from a query into the table. (There's a couple of approaches to maintaining that... brute force wholesale refresh of everything, triggers on the source tables, a transaction queue, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE VIEW userstats 
AS
SELECT
    Users.UserId,
    COUNT(commentId) AS n_comments
FROM
    Users
LEFT JOIN
    UsersComments
ON
    Users.UserId=UsersComments.UserId
GROUP BY
    Users.UserId;
```

As Users and UsersComments tables share a column with the same name, you can use `USING` keyword instead of `ON` to make the query shorter:

```
...
LEFT JOIN
    UsersComments
USING (UserId)
...
```

Comment: You can also use the USING syntax: `FROM Users LEFT JOIN UsersComments USING (UserId)`

Comment: @MatthewSchinckel Yes, it would be shorter

Comment: excelent ! it worked ! what if i want to add another column to the view, lets say for example the amount of contents the user uploaded ? which come from a query such as = "SELECT UserId, count(id) FROM contents GROUP BY UserId" ?

Comment: @gabrielmellace I am not sure, you would be able to group by 2 columns from different tables in 1 query. The easiest way would be to create another view, using the same technique for the COUNT from contents. Or add a subquery here (but it's bad).

Comment: @user4035 i just tried something like a double left join, but it displays the same values in the two columns. I mean, i have two sections on my website A and B . I wanted to make the view show Userid, comments on A, comments on B  but adding a left join to the query you submited showed the same results on A and on B

Comment: @gabrielmellace please, create an sqlfiddle with your query, that doesn't work